# Iterate through DataFrame Incrementally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to iterate through a DataFrame group by group, would the group by function do something like that?

In the first group, the return is calculated from the profit from group 0, the return from the second group is from the profit at the end of group 1. The Actual return is positive if Win_Lose is 1, 0 otherwise

```
   Group  Cost  Win_Lose Return  Profit
0      0  0.00         0      0  $10000
1      1  0.29         1  $2900  $12900
2      1  0.35         0  $3500   $9400
3      1  0.07         1   $700  $11000
4      2  0.16         0  $1760   $9240
5      2  0.19         1  $2090  $11330
6      2  0.27         0  $2970   $8360
```

Comment: You should always try to avoid actually using iteration when it comes to pandas, it is slow compared to vectorized methods.

Comment: Please show your efforts.

Comment: How can i vectorise the problem if the data is processed in groups? thanks

Comment: Filter the dataframe into lesser ones by `Group` and process them. https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/filter_dataframes/